# C program forcing me to have return type but I don't need it.!

Tags: c, tcp, pthreads, posix

I have a TCP/IP application in C. I have 1 header file for handling TCP/IP related things & 1 main file to call all functions. Since problem is happening on client side, I am posting my client side code only.

Here is program.c

```
#include "tcpHeader.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    // all code regarding connecting to server on TCP on another thread.
    // Join here after completing the thread execution
    // It works completely fine upto the next line.
    testFunctionFromMyHeader();

    // after executing below line, program do not continue with 'void' return type of the function. 
    // But it works if I change return type to 'int'
    waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(12345678901LL);

    // program expects me to return an integer on last function call 
    // & all other calls from now.
    // even if I don't need integer return type.
    testFunctionFromMyHeader();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is tcpHeader.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_TCP
#define CLIENT_TCP

// all required headers.
// all global variables

void testFunctionFromMyHeader(){
    printf("Test Function");
}

void waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(unsigned long long args){

    // wait until receiving data from server in recv() function.
    // received 'args' is used in processing the data.
    // process the data received
    // send the confirmation message to server in send() function.
    // Server also received this confirmation without any problem on server side.

    // all code in this function also worked properly.
    // Even the next printf line is also executed.
    printf("All operation completed.");

    // with 'void' return type, next line does not make any difference.
    // But if I return an 'int' then it works.
    return NULL;
}

#endif
```

**It stops on waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(unsigned long long) in program.c**

but If I do like this in program.c, then it works.(Return type on functions from tcpHeader.h are also changed to appropriate types)

```
int confirmation = waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(12345678901LL);
if( confirmation == 0 ){ // 0 or any int value
    int testFunctionReturnedValue = testFunctionFromMyHeader();
        .
        .
        .
        // keep going like this with int return type FOR ALL FUNCTIONS
}
```

Help me to identify the problem. I don't want to use int return types everywhere.

**- Why do it force me to have 'int' return type on waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(unsigned long long) function in my header file**

**- Why do it force me to have 'int' return types on all functions called after that one.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185091/discussion-on-question-by-bhavin-panara-c-program-forcing-me-to-have-return-type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is declared as `void` it means the function will not return anything.

If you use a return statement with a value in such a function, e.g. `return 1;`, you attempt to have it return something. But it is defined as *not* to return something.

Declaring a funcion as `void` has two intentions:

1. Tell the user of the function not to expect a return value.
2. Tell the author of the function not to return anything. If the author wants to communicate something, he should do that using other means (e.g. have a pointer argument to a variable of the caller in which to place a result value, or *adapt the function signature* to return something other than `void`).

For example:

```
void myFunc1(int*result) {
    *result= 1;  // put value 1 in callers variable
    // there is no return statement that returns a value
}
void myFunc2(int*result) {
    *result= 1;  // put value 1 in callers variable
     return;     // leave the function. There is no value to return.
}
```

or:

```
int myFunc(int in) {
    return 2*in;  // leave the function and return a value.
}
```

---

To get back to your problem:

```
int confirmation = waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(12345678901LL);
```

The above says to expect the function to return something and to assign that to variable `conformation`. However,

```
void waitForAMessageFromServerAndSendConfirmation(unsigned long long args) {
    //....
    return NULL;
```

says the function will *not* return anything, but you try to let it return something.

because of these contradictions, your compiler complains.

Comment: As I have written in my comments, that line actually do not make any difference wether I write **return** or **return NULL** or **do not write anything at all**.

Comment: You can use `return` statement in a `void` function when you want to return from it somewhere other than the end.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have written in my post that **(Return type on functions from tcpHeader.h are also changed to appropriate types)**

Comment: @BhavinPanara, I see you have _code_ in your .h file. A .h file should only include definitions (prototypes) and then have file `tcp.c` that has the code for the functions. Further, follow my advise above: either define the funtion to return a value, or not, but not both.

Comment: @BhavinPanara, also make sure warnings of your compiler are turned on. It will give you feedback if you properly return/not return anything.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I receive warnings on compiling, whenever there is something to show, but I do not receive any warnings or errors on runtime.

Comment: @BhavinPanara, ignoring warnings of your compiler may lead to _undefined behavior_ in run-time. It may run correct, it may not and it may run correct sometimes and other times not, i.e. undefined behavior. Fix the warnings!

Comment: Compiler is not giving any warnings or errors for this program. Though it shows me warnings & errors when there are something that I have to change.

Comment: @BhavinPanara, then you don't have warnings enabled. It _should_ complain on what you are doing, and it _will_ complain if warnings are turned on. Check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just commented out everything & uncommented step by step & compiled with **-Wall**,**-Werror** flags & it's working as it should work. Now even if I compile without those flags, it works as expected. I have not changed anything in code. Thank you very much for helping me & for your valuable advice.

Comment: @BhavinPanara, if you haven't changed anything in your code, then you still have errors. If it runs OK then that is by accident, but not by design. A good program is one that does what is expected _by design_. So please fix the warnings, meaning change the code.

Comment: @BhavinPanara: Are you getting any warnings when you compile?  If so, what are they?

Comment: @JohnBode I do not receive any warning when compiling.